# Unified method to embed documents (html/pdf/swf/...) in html

Tags: javascript, iframe

Do you know of any JS lib, or method, that unifies method of embedding external documents (PDF, HTML, SWF, and so on) into div?

Only universal method I'm aware of, is to simply use an `iframe`, but it's said to be *bad idea*. Is there any lib trying to unify this? Or `iframe` way is *the way*?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library, it allows multiple file formats, HTML documents, or components:

[multiBox - for MooTools 1.2](http://www.liamsmart.co.uk/Downloads/multiBox/)